# sql server update + output returning empty value

Tags: sql-server, output

everybody.. I'm a newbie and I'm trying to make my first "little more complicated query" but does not work fully: here it is:

```
if NOT EXISTS (Select id,selector  from Messages where MID='SYCKY')
    Insert into Messages (MID,selector) Values ('SYCKY', 'SaraB|') 
    ELSE 
        if exists (
                     select '1' 
                     from Messages 
                     where charindex ('SaraB|',selector)>0
                  )  
            Update Messages 
            set selector = replace(selector,'SaraB|','') output inserted.selector 
            where MID='SYCKY' 
        ELSE
            Update Messages 
            set selector = selector+'SaraB|' output inserted.selector 
            where MID='SYCKY'
```

it performs the action required, but in the output I have an empty field only

tried also to add an extra field, like this:

```
if NOT EXISTS (Select id,selector  from Messages where MID='SYCKY')  
    Insert into Messages (MID,selector) Values ('SYCKY', 'SaraB|') 
ELSE 
    if exists (select '1' from Messages where charindex ('SaraB|',selector)>0)  
        Update Messages 
        set selector = replace(selector,'SaraB|',''), T='1' output inserted.T  
        where MID='SYCKY' 
    ELSE
        Update Messages 
        set selector = selector+'SaraB|', T='0' output inserted.T 
        where MID='SYCKY'
```

but result is the same: T is empty, while I need to to know if "SaraB|" has been added or deleted from the field

What's wrong?

Comment: Syntax seems to be correct. Are you sure the action is performed (did you do a check via selecting that row?) / the row having `MID='SYCKY'` really exists?

Comment: what "message" do you expect -- both sides of the if statement do an update statement.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for amending my question.
Well, Row with MID='SYCKY' exists, and action is performed correctly (calling it several time it adds and removes the value 'SaraB|' from the field every time), moreover executing it it returns the field 'selector' as required, but it is empty while I expected to receive a value as response.
Actually I tested this on sql manager Lite only..
now I tested with Server Management Studio and it works fine..
therefore is a bug of SQL Manager Lite

Sorry :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure... but maybe this is what you want?

```
if NOT EXISTS (Select id,selector  from Messages where MID='SYCKY')
    Insert into Messages (MID,selector) Values ('SYCKY', 'SaraB|') 
    ELSE 
        if exists (
                     select '1' 
                     from Messages 
                     where charindex ('SaraB|',selector)>0
                  )  
          BEGIN
            Update Messages 
            set selector = replace(selector,'SaraB|','') output inserted.selector 
            where MID='SYCKY';
            SELECT 'If was true';
          END
        ELSE
          BEGIN
            Update Messages 
            set selector = selector+'SaraB|' output inserted.selector 
            where MID='SYCKY';
            SELECT 'If was false';
          END
```

This will "return" different values depending on how the if evaluates.

Comment: Hi!
Thanks for answer.. yes, actually this is what expected, but the query was working well: there was only a bug in SQL Manager Lite that did not show the output value as explained in previous comment.
in fact.. also your solution that works well.. in sql manager lite gives empty result.
Thanks again